# Bidirectional constraint using the implication operator

Tags: system-verilog

In the following code, if a==1, then b==0.  Because of bidirection, if b==0, then my understanding is that a should be 1.  However, the output is different from what I would expect.

```
class ex_sv;

rand bit a;
rand bit b;

constraint c {
   (a==1) -> (b==0);
 }
endclass

module ex_mod;

ex_sv h = new();

initial begin
for( int i = 0; i<10; i++ ) begin
 void'(h.randomize() with {b==0;});
 $display("ITER : %0d a = %0d b = %0d",i, h.a, h.b);
end
end

endmodule
```

```
xcelium> run
ITER : 0 a = 0 b = 0
ITER : 1 a = 0 b = 0
ITER : 2 a = 1 b = 0
ITER : 3 a = 0 b = 0
ITER : 4 a = 0 b = 0
ITER : 5 a = 1 b = 0
ITER : 6 a = 1 b = 0
ITER : 7 a = 0 b = 0
ITER : 8 a = 1 b = 0
ITER : 9 a = 1 b = 0
xmsim: *W,RNQUIE: Simulation is complete.
```

Comment: That isn't my understanding. Consider this: constraint NO_WRITE_ROM {
   (addr < MAX_ROM_ADDR) -> (dir == READ);
 } . You would still be hoping for reads elsewhere in the memory map, else what's the point of the `->` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are expected.

In the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.5.6 *Implication*, 
there is an example similar to yours, with 4-bit variables.

Since you declare two 1-bit variables, there are 4 combinations:

```
{0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}
```

The `c` constraint in the class eliminiates one of these (a=1, b=1),
leaving these 3 combinations:

```
{0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}
```

The inline `with` constraint forces b=0, leaving these 2 combinations:

```
{0,0}, {1,0}
```

This means that `a` could either be 0 or 1, and this is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The implication operator `a == 1 -> b == 0` is logically equivalent to `(a == 0 || b == 0)` (from 18.5.6).

if  `b == 0` then the equation is already satisfied and `a` can take any value, still satisfying the constraint.

if you try to simulate `with a == 0`, then `b` can take any value.

You can experiment `with a == 1` then the only way to satisfy the expression is if `b == 0`.